# Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

While I was setting up React within Django project I came across this error

ModuleBuildError in 
            Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    SyntaxError: C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\assets\js\index.js: Support 
    for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (17:9):

```
  15 | 
  16 | class BodyPartWrapper extends Component {
> 17 |   state = {
     |         ^
  18 | 
  19 |   }
  20 | 

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 
'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

So, I installed @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties and put this in babelrc

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cebula_react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config prod.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.6",
    "webpack": "^4.17.2",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0"
  }
}
```

**babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

However the error is still existed, What is the problem??

Comment: You shouldn't have/need both `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` and `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`. You're rebuilding after install, yes?

Comment: What version of babel are you running?

Comment: share you package json

Comment: I edited my package json

Comment: try running `npx babel-upgrade --write --install`

Comment: @FDisk this didn't work.

Answer (score 114):

**Change**

```
"plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
```

**To**

```
"plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
```

**This worked for me**

Comment: npm i --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

Comment: This dd'nt work for me. I am not ejecting the react app

Comment: Ubuntu 18 - I had to rename `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` and use `module.export` like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916434/babel-plugin-class-properties-react-arrow-functions as discussed on github https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7879#issuecomment-419732313

Comment: `Test suite failed to run; .loose is not a valid Plugin property`

Comment: @DavidCallanan to solve that, just remove the second arg (`{"loose": true}`}

Comment: Seems not to work anymore: `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.`

Answer (score 90):

First install the: **@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties** as dev dependency:

```
npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --save-dev
```

Then edit your .babelrc so it will be exact like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
      ]
  ]
}
```

*.babelrc* file located in the root directory, where *package.json* is.

Note that you should re-start your webpack dev server to changes take affect.

Comment: this one works for me, thanks. I think is the solution for babel 7.0+

Comment: Doesn't work for me in the IDE, with React 18. The React app does work, but there's an ugly error every time the file is scanned in the IDE.

Comment: React 17, that is.

Comment: I am new to the react dev. How I can re-start webpack dev server? I run npm start but this solution does not work for me?

Answer (score 74):

## Solution for webpack project

I just solve this problem by adding `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` into webpack config plugin.
The module section of my `webpack.config.js` looks like this

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env',
                          '@babel/react',{
                          'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']}]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This should be the proper answer when you use webpack, as it is not good to have many configuration files (like webpack.config.js, package.json, and .babelrc) - https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8655#issuecomment-419795548

Comment: worked for me perfectly - was mystified on this for days...thanks much.

Comment: Which one is that `webpack.config.js`? I get 3 currently.

Comment: @BurakKaymakci You should have only one webpack.config.js in react root folder

Answer (score 48):

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    ]
}
```

replace your .babelrc file with above code. it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: If you have ejected create-react-app, change any config in webpack.config.demo and package.json with this config. This means running `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

Comment: This was straight-forward. It so happened that I was missing the `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` dependency.

Comment: it worked, but make sure to install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties first

Answer (score 19):

In my work environment root, .babelrc file was not there. However, following entry in package.json solved the issue.

```
"babel": {
"presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env",
  "@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
]}
```

Note: Don't forget to exit the console and reopen before executing the npm or yarn commands.

Answer (score 8):

**There are two ways to work with react state:**

**Option 1:**
**Just add to package.json:**

```
"babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    }
```

**Option 2:**

**1. Creta a file called **.babelrc** in the root folder.**

****Write in .babelrc:****

```
{ "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"] }
```

2. **Run:**

npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

**3. Run:**

```
npm run dev
or
npm run watch
```

Answer (score 7):

After almost 3 hours of searching and spending time on the same error, I found that I'm using name import for React:

```
import { React } from 'react';
```

which is totally wrong. Just by switching it to:

```
import React from 'react';
```

all the error are gone.
I hope this helps someone. This is my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

the webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const devMode = process.env.Node_ENV !== 'production';
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/App.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'App.js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    port:9090,
    open: 'google chrome',
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },{
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },{
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: devMode ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: devMode ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
    })
  ]
}
```

the package.json

```
{
  "name": "expense-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer looks irrelevant to me. A wrong import is a wrong import, regardless of the plugins you're using.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @MarcoFaustinelli . A wrong import is one of the reasons of this error. So simple and fundamental problem but can happen to everyone. An answer is guide to a problem.

Comment: Upvoted not because it worked for me, but because it helped me understand what the problem was - this error message is not very specific.

Answer (score 7):

Moving the `state` inside the `constructor function` worked for me:

```js
...
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(man) {
    super(man)
    this.state = {}
  }
}
...
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 6):

- Install the plugin-proposal-class-properties
  `npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --save-dev`
- Update your webpack.config.js by adding
  `'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']}]`

Comment: For more information about how to add in the 'plugins', see [this page](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/)

Comment: Doing this is giving me an error along the lines of `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.plugins[1] should be one of these:
   object { apply, … } | function
   -> Plugin of type object or instanceof Function
   Details:
    * configuration.plugins[1] should be an object.
      -> Plugin instance
    * configuration.plugins[1] should be an instance of function
      -> Function acting as plugin`

Answer (score 6):

I find the problem that my `.babelrc` was ignored, However I create `babel.config.js` and add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      {
        helpers: false,
        regenerator: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-flow",
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
  ],
};
```

And it works for me on React Native application, I think this also would help React apps as well.

Comment: `module.exports = {
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}` was enough for me. Can you update your answer and also we should understand why `.babelrc` was ignored

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Babel 7 no longer automatically loads .babelrc. New to Babel in 7, is the concept of a "root" directory. For project-wideconfiguration, Babel will automatically search for a "babel.config.js"

Comment: thanks .. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files/#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10095) GitHub issue if you using create-react-app you should copy your `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` configurations to `webpack.config.js` and delete those.because of htis two line of code  `babelrc: false,configFile: false,` your config in babelrc,.. are useless.
and your `webpack.config.js` is in your `./node_madules/react-scripts/config` folder
I solved my problem like this:

```
{
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },

                  ],
                  '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'
                ],
                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
                .
                .
                .
```

Comment: Did you edit the webpack config in react scripts? That will just cause it to be overwritten in the next npm i? Then should eject.

Comment: I just did whatever on the GitHub page mention. at that time solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the babel parser explicitly. None of the above solutions worked for me. This worked.

```
const ast = parser.parse(inputCode, {
      sourceType: 'module',
      plugins: [
        'jsx',
        'classProperties', // '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      ],
    });
```

Comment: where should i add this code ?
and you use react js ?

Comment: This code is if you are developing a babel plugin. And yes, my plugin is for JSX. https://github.com/Ghost---Shadow/i18nize-react

Answer (score 3):

I'm using yarn. I had to do the following to overcome the error.

```
yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --dev
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
"plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  ]
```

into `.babelrc` works for me.

Answer (score 3):

`yarn add --dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

or

`npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --save-dev`
 *.babelrc*

Answer (score 3):

***For ejected create-react-app projects***

I just solved my case adding the following lines to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
  presets: [
    [
      require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
      { helpers: true },
    ],
    /* INSERT START */
    require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),
    require.resolve('@babel/preset-react'),
      {
      'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
    } 
    /* INSERTED END */
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

If some one working on monorepo following [react-native-web-monorepo](https://github.com/brunolemos/react-native-web-monorepo) than you need to `config-overrides.js` file in `packages/web`. you need to add `resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-ratings'),` in that file...

My complete `config-override.js` file is

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

// our packages that will now be included in the CRA build step
const appIncludes = [
    resolveApp('src'),
    resolveApp('../components/src'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/@react-navigation'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-navigation'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-screens'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-ratings'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-navigation-drawer'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-navigation-stack'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-navigation-tabs'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-elements'),
    resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'),
];

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    // allow importing from outside of src folder
    config.resolve.plugins = config.resolve.plugins.filter(
        plugin => plugin.constructor.name !== 'ModuleScopePlugin'
    );
    config.module.rules[0].include = appIncludes;
    config.module.rules[1] = null;
    config.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].include = appIncludes;
    config.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].options.plugins = [
        require.resolve('babel-plugin-react-native-web'),
        require.resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'),
    ].concat(config.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].options.plugins);
    config.module.rules = config.module.rules.filter(Boolean);
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ __DEV__: env !== 'production' })
    );

    return config
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while trying to transpile some jsx with babel. Below is the solution that worked for me. You can add the following json to your **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      { "targets": { "browsers": ["last 3 versions", "safari >= 6"] } }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the react projects with webpack:

1. Do: npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --save-dev
2. Create `.babelrc` (if not present) file in the root folder where `package.json` and `webpack.config.js` are present and add below code to that:

```js
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

3. Add below code to the `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
            },
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
            }
}
```

4. Close the terminal and run `npm start` again.

Answer (score 1):

**you must install**

npm install @babel/core @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-loader

and

> ***change entry and output***

---

```
const path = require('path')        
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname,'src', 'app.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public","dist",'javascript'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', {
                "targets": "defaults"
              }],
              '@babel/preset-react'
            ],
            plugins: [
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
            ]
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this happens after typescript update, just add `useDefineForClassFields: false` to tsconfig file.

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields

Comment: This resolved the problem in my case, but like you said the error started happening after I updated typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I created a symlink for src/components -> ../../components that caused `npm start` to go nuts and stop interpreting src/components/*.js as jsx, thus giving that same error. All instructions to fix it from official [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8655) were useless.
When I copied back the components directory everything was BACK TO NORMAL!

Comment: did you find any solution to this ? 
i have a application with dependencies installed in normal fashion and i am able to test it,
But when i use the lib from yarn link, it was throwing above error

Comment: @mdsadiq sorry, no, haven't tested the latest ver and the ticket is still open here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9040 maybe you can upvote, thanks.

Comment: A workaround to allow react-scripts to work with symlinks: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/7993/files

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have not mistakenly imported `import BrowserRouter from "react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter";` instead of `import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";`