# Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected token } in JSON at position 450

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, package.json

I face serious problem.

Because when I got a check for json grammer in 'jsonparseronline.com/',

it said all is right, but the error is still existed

> WebpackError at /cebula/1Sun/setting
>               ModuleBuildError in 
>               Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError:
>   C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\package.json: Error while parsing
>   JSON - Unexpected token } in JSON at position 450
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at readConfigPackage (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\package.js:57:20)
>       at C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\utils.js:29:12
>       at cachedFunction (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:33:19)
>       at findPackageData (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\package.js:33:11)
>       at buildRootChain (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:103:85)
>       at loadPrivatePartialConfig (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:57:55)
>       at Object.loadPartialConfig (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:82:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:105:26)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:221)
>       at _next (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:409)
>       at C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:477
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Object. (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:97)
>       at Object.loader (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:50:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:45:12)
>                Request Method:  GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cebula/1Sun/setting Django Version:   2.0.5
>   Exception Type:   WebpackError Exception Value:
>               ModuleBuildError in 
>               Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError:
>   C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\package.json: Error while parsing
>   JSON - Unexpected token } in JSON at position 450
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at readConfigPackage (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\package.js:57:20)
>       at C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\utils.js:29:12
>       at cachedFunction (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:33:19)
>       at findPackageData (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\package.js:33:11)
>       at buildRootChain (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:103:85)
>       at loadPrivatePartialConfig (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:57:55)
>       at Object.loadPartialConfig (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:82:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:105:26)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:221)
>       at _next (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:409)
>       at C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:477
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Object. (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:97)
>       at Object.loader (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:50:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula_react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:45:12)
>                Exception Location:  C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\webpack_loader\loader.py
>   in get_bundle, line 97 Python
>   Executable:   C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
>   Python Version:   3.6.5

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cebula_react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config prod.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.6",
    "webpack": "^4.17.2",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0"
  }
}
```

Could you teach me where is the problem?

Comment: Start removing one line at a time until you find the line with the problem.

Comment: nope, the `JSON` syntax error originates from http://127.0.0.1:8000/cebula/1Sun/setting response... obviously the wrong configuration `JSON` had been posted. good there was the stack-trace, which I'd almost found a little long, at first.

Comment: Looks like the issue is at cebula_react\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\package.js:57

Comment: @MartinZeitler oh thanks, the problem is in response part not in package.json itself! Could I ask one more question? I'm trouble in dealing with <the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237855/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled?noredirect=1#comment91424857_52237855