# Babel Plugin Class Properties – React Arrow Functions

Tags: reactjs, plugins, babeljs, arrow-functions

I am running a React project using npm. After hours of research and experimenting, everywhere says I have to add the following code to my ".babelrc" file, which I do not have in my directory and cannot create:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

But this leads to the following error when I run the code:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/NavBar/Menu.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/ymoondhra/Desktop/yt-web/src/components/NavBar/Menu.js:
Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled
 (20:10):
  18 |     }
  19 | 
> 20 |     fast = () => {
     |          ^
  21 |         this.speed = 100;
  22 |     }
  23 | 
Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' 
section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution to my question after 3 hours:
–create a file called "babel.config.js" in the root directory.
–put this in the file.
–rerun the program (i.e. npm start).

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [ "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react" ],
  plugins: [ "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions", "@babel/plugin-proposal-    class-properties" ]
}
```

Comment: does it need extra set up? i.e package.json

Comment: Took me ages to make it work. I was just changing the filename but was missing the modules.exports. Great post.

Comment: Does it overwrite .babelrc?