# How to fix "Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled" error if it has been already enabled?

Tags: react-native, babeljs, monorepo, react-native-vector-icons, babel-plugin

Im building a crossplatform monorepo application for Web, Android and iOS from this example https://github.com/brunolemos/react-native-web-monorepo and when I added React Native Base to my project I changed my `config-overrides.js` according to this guide https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html for **Web**

But after that I got
`SyntaxError: C:\Users\maksi\Desktop\ecmsk\node_modules\native-base\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\lib\create-icon-set-from-fontawesome5.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled` error.

I tried adding `loose` option to `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` plugin but that didn't work. And I also tried adding `plugins` to my `package.json` and that didn't work either.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/history": "^4.7.2",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.23",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "@types/redux-api-middleware": "^3.0.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.5.2",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.4",
    "react": "16.8.4",
    "react-art": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.10.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-api-middleware": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc -b",
    "prestart": "npm run compile",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run compile -- -w\" \"npm run _start\"",
    "_start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "prebuild": "npm run compile",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "pretest": "npm run compile",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.11.5",
    "concurrently": "*",
    "customize-cra": "^0.4.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.3",
    "typescript": "*"
  }
}
```

**config-overrides.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const {
  override,
  addWebpackAlias,
  babelInclude,
  addBabelPlugins
} = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  addWebpackAlias({
    "react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativePropRegistry": "react-native-web/dist/modules/ReactNativePropRegistry",
    "react-native": "react-native-web"
  }),
  babelInclude([
    path.resolve('src'),
    path.resolve('../components/src'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/react-navigation'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/react-native-easy-grid'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/react-native-drawer'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/react-native-web'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/react-native-tab-view'),
    path.resolve('../../node_modules/static-container'),
  ]),
  addBabelPlugins(
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this issue? I'm following the same example from brunolemos, and whenever I try to add a another library to web's package.json using yarn, I get the same error.

Comment: Same issue, an answer would help a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237855/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the included paths. In my case I have it this way:

```
babelInclude([
    path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-typing-animation'),
    path.resolve('src')
])
```

Paths are relative to the config.overrides file.