# React/ASP - Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: c#, reactjs, babeljs

Have been following a post which details the steps required for setting up [React with C#](https://reciosonny.com/how-to-integrate-reactjs-in-existing-asp-net-mvc-app/). **However**, I am being presented with the following error everytime I try to compile a React application:

`Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled`

```
onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ value: parseInt(e.currentTarget.value, 10) });
};
```

The error message outlines:

`Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4yQ) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.`

Therefore, I altered my package.json to suit:

```
{
 "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config=Scripts/React/config/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-countup": "^4.3.3",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-svg-gauge": "^1.0.10",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  }
}
```

Despite this, I am still receiving the same error. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , possible duplicate [Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237855/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled)

```
"plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
```