# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run very simple code, but I'm getting an error, I didn't use the create react app!

It looks like my babel.config.js file is being ignored!

This is the structure of my small project:
[image]

My html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ReactJS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script  src = 'bundle.js' ></script>
</body> 

</html>
```

My index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

render(<h1>Hello World!!</h1>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

My package json:

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack-dev-server --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
        }]
    },
};
```

And this is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]

};
```

Error when

```
yarn webpack-dev-server --mode development

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /root/treina/front/src/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (4:8):

  2 | import { render } from 'react-dom';
  3 | 
> 4 | render(<h1>Hello World!!</h1>, document.getElementById('app'));
    |        ^

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at Parser._raise (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:757:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:750:17)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8849:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10170:22)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9688:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9668:21)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9538:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9511:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9466:21)
    at Parser.parseExprListItem (/root/treina/front/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10846:18)
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I'm using yarn and the WSL terminal

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62820035/104380

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Just create a `.babelrc` file in the root of your project and add:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: Where to put the `.bablerc` file. I am new to the react dev.

Comment: On the root of your project. Like this:
-node_modules
-src
-.babelrc

Comment: In my case I only need the latter one, since first first one is just for ES6 syntax, which is not related to **react**-jsx.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' in the same folder as your `package.json` file

Comment: <sigh> The team that built/named babel really need to re-read Hitchiker's Guide.  I'd even front them some pocket fluff if they need it.
I keep sticking .babelrc in my ear, but all I get is a Gorgontuous headache.

Comment: While this answer is clearly correct, I would love to know WHY it is correct. Some explanation would make for a more valuable answer.

Answer (score 31):

In my case, Creating "babel.config.js" file with the following content worked.

```
module.exports = {
    presets:[
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's true. according to latest Jest documentation babel.config.js file will work. https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#:~:text=Configure%20Babel%20to%20target%20your%20current%20version%20of%20Node%20by%20creating%20a%20babel.config.js%20file%20in%20the%20root%20of%20your%20project

Answer (score 30):

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/52693007/10952640 solved for me.

You need @babel/preset-react set also on webpack config:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['@babel/env','@babel/preset-react'] },
      },
```

Answer (score 9):

**2021**

I fixed it adding

```
"jsx": "react-jsx"
```

to my "**compilerOptions**" on my **tsconfig.json** file

Comment: sorry, no luck either

Answer (score 7):

Yet another possible cause. I got this error when try to run a project in a command prompt at a path that included symlinks. Changing directory directly into the real path solved the issue.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I was going to a symlink, then to a couple inner directories. When I instead cd'd to the real directories without going through that symlink, it started working for me. Thanks!

Comment: Symlinks will absolutely cause this issue. I have been experimenting with symlinking a directory that's inside a more complex react app to a simple fresh react app and rather than copying the directory in/out I symlinked it so that any changes would be instantly reflected and I could do rapid local development without upgrading the larger app's react version. I tried directly referencing the files in the import statements but relative paths that point outside the react app's src directory is not allowed. But symlinking causes this issue. Frustrating.

Answer (score 6):

The solution that worked for me was when I discovered `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` contained:

```
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
```

By setting `babelrc: true,` I was finally able to get .babelrc changes to work. I'm guessing the `configFile:` parameter is what you will need to change. (Note, the babelrc appears to need to go into `src/` for react-scripts to find it, reasonably likely to also be true for babel.config.js.)

This may apply to others if you've run npm run eject on your create-react-app project. This will create the webpack.config.js file and defaults babelrc and configFile to false.

Answer (score 4):

I remade my project from scratch and realized that I was wrong to not include the "D" at the end of the command:

```
yarn add webpack-dev-server -D
```

Now it's working!

Comment: No need to make project again, the above command will do needful.

Answer (score 3):

Mmm i think the problem is in your babel, try this:

1. npm i --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
2. add loose:true in your babelrc

Comment: Looks like you have to include some options in your rules inside the webpack.config `options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env',
                          '@babel/react',{
                          'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']}]
            }`

Comment: I did it, same problem

Answer (score 3):

Adding another answer to the mix... the project I was looking at when I hit this was built off `create-react-app` using react scripts v4 and React 17. The warning was showing for me in relation to the source code for a third-party module, something like:

```
Failed to compile.                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
./node_modules/@third-party/ui-components/src/components/Header.js 
SyntaxError: C:\Development\app\node_modules\@third-party\ui-components\src\components\Header.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (142:5)
```

The problem turned out to be that someone had mistakenly added the import for the third-party component as follows:

```
import { Header } from '@third-party/ui-components/src';
```

Instead of:

```
import { Header } from '@third-party/ui-components';
```

So, webpack was trying to use the original source code for the package instead of the compiled export. And, checking into `react-scripts`, the module loader for JS external to the app is set up as follows:

```json
// Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
// Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
{
  test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
  exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
  loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
  options: {
    babelrc: false,
    configFile: false,
    compact: false,
    presets: [
      [
        require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
        { helpers: true },
      ],
    ],
    cacheDirectory: true,
    // ----- 8< -----
  },
}
```

Fixing up the import path by removing the `/src` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I am using React `18` and above version.

Two simple steps:

- First check if you have `"@babel/preset-react"` added to your package.json. If no, then `install i  @babel/preset-react`.
- Update your `babel.config.js` with `"@babel/preset-react"` value. remember to add `automatic` in configuration.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
    ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }],
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In my package.json, I added:

```
 "babel": {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/react",
    "@babel/env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error, my problem was that during rebase I lost a brace somewhere so my package.json wasn't working properly - if your babel is showing errors like this - try checking if your package.json has brackets properly set up

Comment: There are two other answers that not only mentions package.json, but also shows an example. Does your answer really add anything to those answers?

Comment: it doesn't add to the answers of others, that's why it is a separate answer...if I saw this answer, it would have helped me, that sometimes this error can occur from typos/missing brackets....

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Babel 7 and yarn workspaces or a monorepo and getting this error you need to tell Babel to transpile files outside your package directory.

In your webpack 5 config put babelrcRoots: ['../*'] in your js test object options. Here's mine for example:

```
  {
    use: ['babel-loader'],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
      babelrcRoots: ['../*']
    }
  },
```

See other options in [this github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8309)

Answer (score 1):

For Rails/React, run the line below:

```
$ bin/rails webpacker:install:react
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the webpacker.yml file if using react with rails add jsx extension.

```
  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the test doesn't work in VSCode only. I'm using yarn workspace and CRA as one of the workspaces.

This means the solution is to ignore the failing VSCode tests and start the tests in command line instead:

`yarn workspace frontend test`

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are getting this error while building Remix app, change the extension of file from .js to .jsx/.tsx or check with tsconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when converting a create-react-app to a vite application and I didn't change all the .js files to .jsx files. So just make sure to change all your .js files to .jsx files if converting.

Answer (score -2):

```
module.exports = {
   plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
   presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
```

Make changes according the the link below to your babel.config.js

From https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/create-react-native-app

and then just add the presets as shown above, it will work.

Comment: An answer needs to be complete enough to work even if links break. It's fine to refer to an external resource to give credit or provide pointers for optional information; but it needs to be supplemental to the answer, not essential.