# SyntaxError: unknown: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am making my first ever unit tests with Jest and React Testing Library on my react app.
This is a project I took over and has some pre-existing configuration and test setup which I'll admit I may not fully understand.

How I got to this error is this:
I already had one test up and running testing a component that doesn't use redux.
My next test needed to test a component that uses Redux and so I started to look at totally using React Testing Library and dropping Enzyme all together as the Enzyme isnt compatible with the latest React.

I kept getting an error along the lines of 'cannot import modules outside of node modules' and found out that babel cannot parse ES6.
And so I have been scouring the internet looking for solutions...
I have tried a few methods:
`@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx` 
`@babel/preset-react`
most recently

However it seems it was not being picked up on as I was still getting the same error with the same suggestion which was:

> Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
> If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.

I have added this to the presets and plugins of my babel config in my package-lock but still got the same error.

I also tried adding a `.babelrc` and `babel.config.js` file with the same preset and plugins but still get the same error.

There was some pre-existing code which I think could potentially be screwing things up somehow but I do not entirely understand it I'll be honest.

This is my package-lock:

```
{
  "name": "hiro-flash",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@sentry/react": "^5.29.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^5.29.2",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "axios-cache-adapter": "^2.3.3",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "detect-browser": "^2.5.0",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jest-cli": "26.6.3",
    "jest-esm-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jszip": "^3.6.0",
    "jszip-utils": "^0.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-business-days": "^1.1.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "npm": "^5.10.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^3.3.3",
    "react-dates": "^21.2.1",
    "react-datetime": "^2.15.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.9.10",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-ga": "3.2.0",
    "react-hotjar": "^2.2.1",
    "react-hover-observer": "^2.1.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^2.1.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "react-sizes": "^1.0.4",
    "react-table": "6.8.6",
    "react-throttle-render": "^2.0.0",
    "react-tippy": "^1.2.2",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.9",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.11",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-api-middleware": "^2.3.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "jest-esm-transformer",
      "^.+\\.(mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "mjs",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "extensionsToTreatAsEsm": [
    ".js",
    ".jsx",
    ".ts"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "window": {
      "location": {
        "protocol": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.14.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "sinon": "^7.4.1"
  }
}
```

this is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { PriceMonitor }  from '../../components/priceMonitor/PriceMonitor';
describe('Price Monitor', () => {
    const getTree = (activeUser = 'Test User 1', isOriginalUser = true, openPriceMonitorModal = jest.fn(),
        resetActiveUser = jest.fn()) => {
        const props = {
            activeUser,
            openPriceMonitorModal,
            isOriginalUser,
            resetActiveUser,
        }
        const component = renderer.create(<PriceMonitor {...props} />);
        return component.toJSON();
    }
    const mockOnClick = jest.fn((username, newOriginalValue) => getTree(username, newOriginalValue));
    it('renders original user (Test User 1)', () => {
        const tree = getTree();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    it('changes user onClick (Test User 1 -> Test User 2)', () => {
        const tree = getTree();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot(); 
        expect(mockOnClick('Test User 2', false)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    it('renders non original user (Test User 2)', () => {
        const tree = getTree('Test User 2', false)
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    it('resets user onClick (Test User 2 -> Test User 1)', () => {
        const tree = getTree('Test User 2', false);
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
        expect(mockOnClick('Test User 1', true)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

And then 2 files which were pre-existing,
this is test.js:

```
'use strict';
// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'test';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
process.env.PUBLIC_URL = '';
// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});
// Ensure environment variables are read.
require('../config/env');
const jest = require('jest');
const argv = process.argv.slice(2);
// Watch unless on CI or in coverage mode
if (!process.env.CI && argv.indexOf('--coverage') < 0) {
  argv.push('--watch');
}
jest.run(argv);
```

fileTransform.js inside my jest folder:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

// This is a custom Jest transformer turning file imports into filenames.
// http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename) {
    return `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename))};`;
  },
};
```

Theres also a webpack.config.dev.js but Im not sure how much that is effecting this problem

Im a newb so apologies if this isnt clear enough - will be happy to provide more info.

Comment: Have you checked the answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63005011/9256189

Comment: Yes - I tried adding .babelrc / babel.config.js file but same error still
the other answers I dont think are applicable as I dont have a tsconfig.json file nor anything about babel or eject in my webpack.config.js