# Nx.dev Gatsby throws error in plugin gatsby-plugin-translate-urls - Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin, nx.dev

Hi in Gatsby I am getting error

ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

/project/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-translate-url
s/utils/wrap-page-element.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't
currently enabled (11:5):

We are using Nx.dev so we created template for Gatsby and there added our Gatsby project.

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "allowJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": false,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true
    },
    "files": [],
    "include": [],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
        }
    ],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "babel-preset-gatsby",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": []
}
```

I really don't know where is the problem. When I comment plugin `gatsby-plugin-translate-urls` build succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

According to: [Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005011/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-jsx-isnt-currently-enabled)

I would recommend you to change your `.babelrc` config to the following and give it a new try:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "babel-preset-gatsby",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
                }
            },
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": []
}
```

Also, according to https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26605 supports the theory that `gatsby-plugin-translate-urls` messes all up because the usage of its internal `Link`

```
import {TranslatedLink} from "gatsby-plugin-translate-urls"
```

Double-check the naming and the import type