# Why cant i run this react calendar in my local environment on Chrome says' Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (531:7):'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

Wanted to add this calendar (https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dirac-9my5zx?file=/src/index.js)  component to my application but not able to solve this error, any insight to solve the problem would be helpful

I tried pasting the Babel config files from other questions with similar problem but of no avail.

Also not able to run the calendar on its own after forking either

Answer (score 0):

create a .babelrc file in the root folder

```
{
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

For more details you can refer to this question. Let me know if this works

[Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005011/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-jsx-isnt-currently-enabled)

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work dont know why

Comment: Have you check other answer as well?

Comment: Yes I have tried them all sadly