# Do I have to build the React Javascript project before publishing on npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am publishing a React JavaScript component on npm and I was wondering that do I have to build the project and deploy the build folder or not ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my research you do not have to upload a build folder, because every npm packages stores at node_modules folders after installation so i did not found any build folder at there as a deployed.This is my opinion hope it will help you further.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69971466/publish-react-javascript-component-to-npm?noredirect=1 do you know anything about this issue ?

Comment: please refer some links given below, may you find your proper solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005011/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-jsx-isnt-currently-enabled

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820035/babel-throwing-support-for-the-experimental-syntax-jsx-isnt-currently-enabled