# How to resolve ''Support for experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled"?

Tags: react-testing-library, ts-jest, react-typescript, babel-jest

This problem occurs when I attempt to run unit tests with React Testing Library using Jest. I'm working on a React-TypeScript project and in the currently testing `.tsx` file have some images with `.svg` extension. When I try to run `npm run test <filename.spec.tsx>` I'm getting the following error.

[image]

This my `jest.config.ts` file:

```
export default {
  preset: '../../../jest.preset.js',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../../coverage/libs/shared/dashboard-widgets',
};
```

`package.json` file:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.21.2",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.0",
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Babel throwing Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820035/babel-throwing-support-for-the-experimental-syntax-jsx-isnt-currently-enabled)