# How to get Jest working with Vite - Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: vite

I've added the various dependencies as shown below here but I am still getting the message

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (8:12):
```

Note this is for a brand new Vite project to see how to get jest working with react in a vite project. I have not added any specific application code yet so whatever the issue and solution is, it should apply to many others as a template

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "react-testing-library": "^8.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
 SyntaxError: /home/durrantm/Dropnot/vite/thedeiscorecard-vite/src/App.test.tsx:
 Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (8:12):
                                                                                                                                                                        
       6 | describe('Main app test', () => {                                                                                                                            
       7 |   it('renders the App', () => {                                                                                                                              
    >  8 |     render(<App />);                                                                                                                                         
         |            ^                                                                                                                                                 
       9 |     const title = screen.getByText(/Vite \+ React/i);                                                                                                        
      10 |     expect(title).toBeInTheDocument();                                                                                                                       
      11 |   });                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
    Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to
    the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
    If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx
    (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx)
    to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

The problem seems to be the ability of Vite to use ESM but Jest is still in commonJS world.

There is a solution to this which is to use the experimental feature for ESM in jest as detailed at https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

However, even though I followed the advice given there I am still getting the error about "'jsx' isn't current enabled"

I followed the advice to add a babel.config.json (even though esm doesn't use bable), so I added a `babel.config.json` file.  Unfortunately this gave me

```
 SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

so this is not the correct solution and I am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've went exactly down the same path you did and hit the same wall.

I strongly recommend using vitest to set up the configuration. It's a breeze compared to having to jump all the hurdles to set up the testing environment from scratch.

You can find a very simple guide here https://codingpr.com/test-your-react-app-with-vitest-and-react-testing-library/.

You get access to the same methods as jest and have jsdom support, but all in a matter of minutes to get it working, already pre-packed for vite.

I spent over 4 hours trying to set up the Vite environment and jumping over hurdles with the syntax and babel setup, and this way I got a testing environment running in 3 minutes.

Hope it helps you or anyone who struggles with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

install ts-jest & put this in your jest config file.

```json
    "transform": {
       "^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
```

- > [Babel throwing Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820035/babel-throwing-support-for-the-experimental-syntax-jsx-isnt-currently-enabled)