# babel issue when running jest in lerna reactjs repo

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, lerna

I've recreated the issue in this repo:

https://github.com/umarmw/lopital-sdk

whereby when executing `lerna run test`, it throws this error:

```
FAIL __tests__/doctor.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /codebox/lopital-sdk/packages/doctor/__tests__/doctor.test.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (9:24):

       7 | describe('doctor', () => {
       8 |     it('should be selectable by class "foo"', function() {
    >  9 |         expect(shallow(<Doctor title="MO" />).is('.btn-doctor')).toBe(true);
         |                        ^
      10 |       });
      11 | 
      12 |       it('should mount in a full DOM', function() {

    Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
    If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

I've added this `@babel/preset-react` in the babel preset, but it's not solving the issue.

Any idea?

Comment: did you installed `@babel/preset-react` as well?

Comment: Have you tried changing the format to `jsx`?

Comment: also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237855/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled

Comment: @yaya, I tried.. but still not working.

Comment: @Rashomon, its a typescript project. The extension should be either ts or tsx.

Comment: @UmarWaliyullah try `"loose": true` as well, as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237855/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled

Comment: @yaya, I've added this also, but no effect. I've also update the repo codes with the other suggestions from the SO posts..

Comment: I've fixed it by adding the `babel.config.json` in each package folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the above issue by adding `babel.config.json` inside each package folder as `lerna` will try to execute the code relative to each package.