# npm run-script ssr (server side rendering not working)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, seo, server-side-rendering

I was trying SSR for SEO purposes in my react app.
Getting these errors (..which are not actual errors according to react).

first I got err in

```
componenDidMount=()=>
```

after commenting this

I got err in

```
state={}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcc7k.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEIAO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.
change this:

```
componentDidMount=()=>{}
state={};
```

to this:

```
componentDidMount() {

}
this.state = {}
```

In case it doesn't work, [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237855/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled)