# error - support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to setup engagespot in my angular app as per the documentation https://documentation.engagespot.co/docs/javascript-guide/using-angular-package

here is the code.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import { render } from "@engagespot/client";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("engagespotBellIcon") engagespotBellIcon: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    render(this.engagespotBellIcon.nativeElement, {
      apiKey: "<api_key>",
      userId: "user@sample.com",
      theme: {} //Theme Object to Customize the look and feel of the notification inbox.
    });
  }
}
```

But it's showing error

```
SyntaxError
/node_modules/@engagespot/core/dist/esm/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (1:1717):
```

**Update**
I tried babel configurations as mentioned here - [Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237855/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled). But the same error.

Comment: strange thing I noticed. It works in my local machine when I tried. I was trying in codesandbox all this time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237855/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled)

Comment: no it didn't work

Comment: I tried multiple babel configurations in codesandbox, but the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Engagespot maintainer here.

This has been fixed in the latest version (v1.1.3) of `@engagespot/client`.

You can check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Engagespot/engagespot/tree/master/examples/examples-angular)